# Local equations of codimension 1 subvarieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a smooth affine variety and $X'\subset X$ be a codimension 1 subvariety of X.Let $x \in X'$.In this situation,there exist $f_{x}\in \mathcal{O}_{x,X}$ such that $f_{x}\cdot \mathcal{O}_{x,X}=I(X')\cdot \mathcal{O}_{x,X}$(this is called a local
equation of $X'$ at $x$).

Is it true that there exist a open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $y\in U \Rightarrow$ local equation of $X'$ at $y$
is $f_{x}$ ?

Comment: This is true. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to prove,but I don't know how to find such neighborhood of $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Variety $X$ is affine, thus $X=Spec(A)$ for some $\Bbb C$ algebra $A$.

The point $x$ is determined by a maximal ideal $m_x\subset A$ and ${\cal O}_{X,x}=A_m$ (the localization of $A$ in $m$).

Now, by definition of localization, $f_x=f/g$ with $f$ and $g$ in $A$ and $g\not\in m$. Consider the open set $U_g:=\{ g\neq 0\}\subset X$. We have that $U_g=Spec(A_g)$ (where $A_g$ is the localization of $A$ with the multiplicative set $\{ g^n / \; n\in \Bbb N\}$). The divisor $Z:=\{f/g=0\}$ in $U_g$ coincides with the the restriction of $X'$ to $U_g$. Indeed, the restriction of them to the generic point (which is dense) is the same.

Thus your $U$ is, for instance, $U_g$.